# Python program to prompt user for 10 character string. Once a string that meets the length requirement is entered, print the 3rd through the 10th

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

This is where I am so far... What is the best way to put these together so that the program will keep prompting for user input until 10 characters have been met?

```py
def char_frequency(str1):
    char_dict = {}
    for n in str1:
        keys = char_dict.keys()
        if n in keys:
            char_dict[n] += 1
        else:
            char_dict[n] = 1
    return char_dict

print(char_frequency('elevator'))

def string_length(str1):
    count = 0
    for char in str1:
        count += 1
    return count

print(string_length('adkjfaslnfafs'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    a = input("Please enter a text: ")
    if len(a.strip()) >= 10:
        print(a[2:]) # Do whatever you want with the input
        break
```